# Why does jQuery ajax work in Chrome but not Firefox or IE?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I've tried a few flavors of jQuery ajax.  `$.ajax ,  $.getJSON  & $.get`  all work great in Chrome.
However none work in Firefox or IE. I'm reading a json file from the same directory.
The json originates from desk.com's api.  I'm using php & cURL to grab & save the json.

In `$.ajax` I've also tried defining the `dataType`
Firebug gives no errors.
console.log the ajax return in firebug and it returns an Object with all of the json data but not displaying to page.
When alerting it gives [object Object]

JS:

```
function getDesk($group_number)
{   
    now = Date();
    unixTimeMS = Date.parse(now);  
    var tempHtml = '<table class="table table-bordered" id="desk_data_table">'+
        '<thead style="background-color:#eee">'+
        '<tr>'+
        '<th>Available</th>'+
        '<th>Name</th>'+
        '<th>Created</th>'+
        '<th>Updated</th>'+
        '<th>Current login</th>'+
        '<th>Last login</th>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '</thead>'+
        '<tbody id="desk_data_table_body">';
    $url = $group_number + ".json";
    $.get( $url, function( resp ) {
        $.each( resp['_embedded']['entries'], function( key, value ) {
            updated = value['updated_at'].replace(/[TZ+]/g, " ");
            updatedKeep = value['updated_at'].replace(/[TZ+]/g, " ");
            updated = Date.parse(updated);
            difference = unixTimeMS - updated;
            if(difference < 604800000){
                lastLogin = value['last_login_at'].replace(/[TZ+]/g, " ");
                created = value['created_at'].replace(/[TZ+]/g, " ");
                updated = value['updated_at'].replace(/[TZ+]/g, " ");
                current = value['current_login_at'].replace(/[TZ+]/g, " ");

                if(value.available == true){
                    tempHtml += "<tr style='background-color:#9de7a2;'><td >" + value['available'] + "</td>";
                } else {
                    tempHtml += "<tr style='background-color:#f0a0a0;'><td >" + value['available'] + "</td>";
                }

                tempHtml += "<td nowrap='nowrap'> " +value['name']+"</td>";
                tempHtml += "<td nowrap='nowrap'> " + created + "</td>";
                tempHtml += "<td nowrap='nowrap'> " + updatedKeep + "</td>";
                tempHtml += "<td nowrap='nowrap'> " + current + "</td>";
                tempHtml += "<td nowrap='nowrap'> " + lastLogin + "</td></tr>"; 
            }
            else{ false; }
        });
        tempHtml += "</tbody></table>";
        $('#' + $group_number).html(tempHtml);
    });
}

getDesk(491244);
```

webpage:

```
<div id="491244"></div>
```

THE JSON [ filename = 491244.json ]

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "entries": [
            {
                "avatar": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/26536",
                "available": false,
                "created_at": "2014-04-08T19:10:41Z",
                "current_login_at": "2015-10-21T14:21:27Z",
                "email": "Matthew.Jamison@email.com",
                "email_verified": true,
                "id": 21912353,
                "last_login_at": "2015-10-19T20:50:22Z",
                "level": "siteadmin",
                "name": "Matt Jamison",
                "public_name": "Matt Jamison",
                "updated_at": "2015-10-21T14:21:27Z"
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Get out of the habit of using global variables in your functions, they're a common cause of problems. Use the `var` keyword to declare your variables. I wonder if one of those variables is conflicting with something, try making them all local and see if it helps.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through the callback function in the debugger?

Comment: Changed everything to local variables with var keyword.  And I have tried debugger but I'm new so I don't fully understand it.  Are you on codementor.io ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that's because of the condition

```
   if(difference < 604800000){
```

That varies because of the inconsistency in both date object and the current time milles as well.

Check with that by debugging or just get rid of that for some time.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$.getJSON` if you want it to parse the JSON automatically. And `resp[_embedded][entries]` should be `resp._embedded.entries` or resp["_embedded"]["entries"]. When you don't quote the names, it uses them as variables, but they have no values.

Comment: I have used `$.getJSON` successfully in Chrome.  It is not working in Firefox.

Comment: It can't possibly work the way you wrote it in the question. You need quotes around those property names.

Comment: Unless you have global variables `_embedded = '_embedded'; entries = 'entries';`

Comment: If these functions didn't work in Firefox, thousands of web sites wouldn't work. So it must be something you're doing that's interfering. Without more code from your application it's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong. Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: I've updated it with the code I'm actually using.  I think the issue is in the $.each @Barmar

Comment: i wonder if '$' is messing things up. `function getDesk($group_number)...` -> `function getDesk(group_number)...` ? (and update other references.) (and $url. leave the $ to jquery.)

Comment: There's nothing special about `$` in variable names. Some people like to use a naming convention where variables beginning with `$` contain jQuery objects rather than "ordinary" values. But Javascript doesn't care about that.